# Scope struct allocated on the stack

Tags: c, struct, scope

I am reading and learning on C. I have read many similar questions but most of them seem to be a counter example of what I am experiencing or I still don't understand the concept of object allocation on the heap and on the stack.

Suppose I have a struct like in the following example:

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    char* word;
    struct list_element* next;
}list_element;
```

I want to write a function that initialises a `struct` of the type `list_element`.
What I would do from what I learned from text books is create the struct on the heap using `malloc` so everything is still visible outside the initialiser function.

```
list_element* init_list_element(int x, char* word) {

    list_element* le = (list_element*)malloc(sizeof(list_element));
    le->word = word;
    le->x = x;

    return le;
}
```

For truly understanding the subject I tried to write an alternative initialiser function that allocates the `struct` on the stack. Which should result in an error later when trying to access the attributes because the variable should have gone out of scope.

```
list_element init_list_element(int x, char* word) {
    list_element le;
    le.word = word;
    le.x = x;

    return le;
}
```

However when creating a struct with the second implementation and trying to access for example the attribute x the code doesn't break. Why is this? Shouldn't the variable `le` be gone out of scope and therefor inaccessible when trying to printf its attributes?

```
list_element test = init_list_element(123,"test");
printf("%s, %i", test.word, test.x);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list_element test = init_list_element(123,"test");
```

You are creating a copy of the struct created inside the second function, therefore you can still access it, but it's just a copy.

In C, everything you assign to variable is a copy.

Example:

```
list_element le1 = {1, NULL, NULL};
list_element le2 = le1;
```

le2 will contain a copy of le1 and not the original le1. In other words, the following will not change the value of le1:

```
le2.x = 3;
printf("%d",le1.x); // 1
printf("%d",le2.x); // 3
```

Comment: so if the second function from my original question would also return a pointer and I return &le with le the list_element created on the stack then the there would be an error?

Comment: It should give a warning if you try to return address of local variable. So the best way to do this is using malloc to reserve some space in the heap @tim_a

Answer (score 1):

The variable `le` has gone out of scope, but you are not accessing `le`. The `init_list_element()` function returns a copy of `le`, and the contents of that copy are assigned to `test`.

The members of `test` then contain the same data that `le` originally did.